# MySQL category with parent_id - SELF Join

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

My SQL table called `categories` has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
   id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   parent_id int,
   name varchar(50),
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I would like to know if it's possible to JOIN the same table and present the `parent_id` name. I can do this by PHP code, but I would like, because of performance issues, to retrieve as SQL Query.

**[See example at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0ee23/4)**

I've managed to JOIN the table, but somehow the values aren't right. For example, the result of SQLFiddle retrieves:

```
    ID |    Name     | Parent Category Name
   -----------------------------------
    1       Meats          Steaks
```

Which is wrong, it should be:

```
    ID |    Name     | Parent Category Name
   -----------------------------------
    3       Steaks         Meats
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` and you have to join on the `id` equal to the `parent_id` of the other table like this:

```
SELECT     c.id, c.name, parents.name AS `Parent Category Name`
FROM       categories AS c
INNER JOIN  categories AS parents ON parents.id = c.parent_id
ORDER BY   c.name ASC;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0ee23/19)

This will give you:

```
| ID |   NAME | PARENT CATEGORY NAME |
|----|--------|----------------------|
|  3 | Steaks |                Meats |
```

---

If you want to include those categories with no parent, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can do a self join.  For the syntax to work you need to use aliases:

```
select c.id, c.name, cp.name as parent_category_name
from categories c left join
     categories cp
     on c.parent_id = cp.id;
```

In your query, you just have the join in the wrong direction.  I would suggest that you use more meaningful table aliases than `category` and `cat`.  In the above `cp` is intended to be the row for the parent.

Your `on` clause should be:

```
SELECT     category.id, category.name, cat.name AS `Parent Category Name`
FROM       categories category LEFT JOIN
           categories cat
           ON cat.id = category.parent_id
ORDER BY   category.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
SELECT     a.id, a.name,(select b.name from categories b where b.id=a.parent_id) AS `Parent Category Name`
 FROM       categories a
```